# How to check successive values in a CSV file by awk?

Tags: awk

In a two-column CSV, I want to check the successive numbers (the values are integers):

```
1,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
7,1
10,1
11,1
4,2
5,2
6,2
10,2
5,3
5,7
5,8
5,9
```

I tried

```
awk -F, '
{
    if($1==a+1) { n+=1 } 
    else { n = 1 } 
{a=$1}
} {print $1"," n}
' file.txt
```

to produce

```
1,1,1
4,1,1
5,1,2
6,1,3
7,1,4
10,1,1
11,1,2
4,2,1
5,2,2
6,2,3
10,2,1
5,3,1
5,7,1
5,8,1
5,9,1
```

where the third column counts the successive rows with respect to the first column.

1. Is my approach is correct (particularly performance-wise because it is a huge file)?
2. What is the best way to calculate the fourth column based on the second column (counting the successive values in the second column)?

This is the expected output including the fourth column.

```
1,1,1,1
4,1,1,1
5,1,2,1
6,1,3,1
7,1,4,1
10,1,1,1
11,1,2,1
4,2,1,1
5,2,2,1
6,2,3,1
10,2,1,1
5,3,1,1 
5,7,1,1
5,8,1,2
5,9,1,3
```

My idea is to sort the produced 3-column CSV (`sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2n`) and do the same thing with the second column, but I am not sure.

*EDIT:* I made a mistake in the first dataset. When we count the first column, the second column is constant, and vice versa.

Comment: What are the expected values for your fourth column?

Comment: @Shawn it was my fault, I should have provided it. I will update the question.

Comment: What is your complete expected output for sample provided in question?

Comment: @anubhava I updated the data samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
}
{
    $3 = ($1 == p1+1 ? $3+1 : 1)
    $4 = ($1 == p1 && $2 == p2+1 ? $4+1 : 1)
}
{
   p1 = $1
   p2 = $2
} 1' file.csv
```

```
1,1,1,1
4,1,1,1
5,1,2,1
6,1,3,1
7,1,4,1
10,1,1,1
11,1,2,1
4,2,1,1
5,2,2,1
6,2,3,1
10,2,1,1
5,3,1,1
5,7,1,1
5,8,1,2
5,9,1,3
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested  on shown samples(basically re-designed OP's code in more awkish way :) , thanks to OP for letting know in comments).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  count=$1-prev==1 && prev?++count:"1"
  print $0,count
  prev=$1
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- In this approach we haven't re-assigned current line and simply printing the value of current line along with count value, which should be less time taking.

Output will be as follows.

```
1,10,1
4,10,1
5,10,2
6,11,3
7,14,4
10,9,1
11,2,2
```

NOTE: In case you want to sort output after awk's calculations then we could further use `| sort` to perform sorting on 3rd column IMHO.

Comment: you modified my code for the first question. Do you have any suggestion for calculating the fourth column (by counting the second column)? The main question is indeed the second one.

Comment: @Googlebot,in case you want to sort output after `awk`'s calculations then we could further use ` | sort` to perform sorting on 3rd column IMHO.

Comment: it was my mistake, the second column should be constant when counting the first column. I updated the dataset. I provided incorrect random values for the second column.